# How my date_view() function would work in this code as I am getting "call to undefined function" error?

Tags: php

This is my HTML file. I am getting an error like this:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function date_view()
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\cse391project3\assignment3.php:36 Stack trace:
> #0 {main}  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cse391project3\assignment3.php on line 36

The line number isn't accurate but I am getting the error due to calling date_view() function

```html
<html>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assign3_css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <form class="input-group"  action="assign3_conn.php"  method="post">
    <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Alex Smith">
    
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Alex">
    
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">SID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="st_id" placeholder="12345678">
    
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
    
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn"> Submit </button> 
    
    </div>
  
  
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Section</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1 &nbsp hi &nbsp <?php date_view(1) ?> &nbsp <?php seat_view(1) ?></option>
      <option>2 &nbsp hello &nbsp <?php date_view(2) ?> &nbsp <?php seat_view(2) ?></option>
      <option>3 &nbsp tata &nbsp <?php date_view(3) ?> &nbsp <?php seat_view(3) ?></option>
      <option>4 &nbsp bye &nbsp <?php date_view(4) ?> &nbsp <?php seat_view(4) ?></option>
    </select>
    </div>
  
  
    </form>


</html>
```

This is my PHP file

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$stid=$_POST['st_id'];

$conn= new mysqli('localhost','root','','assign3');
if($conn->connect_error){
    die('Connection failed');
}
function date_view ($num) {
    $s="select date_time from prac_slot where id='$num'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$s);
    $num1=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
    if($num1==1){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo $row["date_time"];
        }
    }
}

function seat_view ($num){
    $s="select seat from prac_slot where id='$num'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$s);
    $num1=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
    if($num1==1){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo $row["seat"];
        }
    }
}

$stmt=$conn->prepare("insert into student(name,f_name,sid,email)
values(?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$name,$fname,$stid,$email);
$stmt->execute();
echo "Registration success";
$stmt ->close();
$conn-> close();
```

?>

Answer (score -1):

This can not work while your html file doesn't know anything about your php file, and html can't handle php code. So you have to change the extension of your html to php, then include your functions on the top of the file or put the two files in one php file, also, you have to check if the form is posted !

```
    <?php
        
        $conn= new mysqli('localhost','root','','assign3');
        if($conn->connect_error){
            die('Connection failed');
        }
        function date_view ($num) {
            $s="select date_time from prac_slot where id='$num'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$s);
            $num1=mysqli_num_rows($result);
            
            if($num1==1){
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo $row["date_time"];
                }
            }
        }
        
        function seat_view ($num){
            $s="select seat from prac_slot where id='$num'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$s);
            $num1=mysqli_num_rows($result);
            
            if($num1==1){
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo $row["seat"];
                }
            }
        }
        
    ?>
    <html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assign3_css.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <form class="input-group"  action="assign3_conn.php"  method="post">
        <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Alex Smith">
        
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Alex">
        
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">SID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="st_id" placeholder="12345678">
        
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
        
        <button type="submit" class="submit-btn"> Submit </button> 
    
    </div>
  
  
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Section</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1 &nbsp hi &nbsp <?php date_view(1) ?> &nbsp <?php seat_view(1) ?></option>
      <option>2 &nbsp hello &nbsp <?php date_view(2) ?> &nbsp <?php seat_view(2) ?></option>
      <option>3 &nbsp tata &nbsp <?php date_view(3) ?> &nbsp <?php seat_view(3) ?></option>
      <option>4 &nbsp bye &nbsp <?php date_view(4) ?> &nbsp <?php seat_view(4) ?></option>
    </select>
    </div>
  
  
    </form>


</html>
```

also be aware of sql injections

Comment: This doesn't work at all as I am getting                                                                           
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\cse391project3\assignment3.php on line 2

Comment: what your code looks like now ? Are you calling assign3_conn.php withou posted data ?

Comment: You can put a value on <button type="submit" ... value="submited"/> for example and check if (isset($_POST('submit') && $_POST('submit') ==='submited') {... then your code. Also check like this for others inputs.